# Having trouble connecting to SQL Server database from VBA using ADO connection

Tags: sql-server, database, vba, database-connection, connection-string

I want to connect to a SQL Server database without using DSN. I'm receiving an error when trying to connect to said database. The error is

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

My connection string looks like this:

```
"ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=lokdb; UID=secret;PWD=secret;APP=Microsoft Open Database Connectivity;WSID=" & Environ$("COMPUTERNAME") & ";Network=DBMSSOCN;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=EDMS-Lok"`
```

I am able to connect to the default database on the server with the credentials specified if I remove the `DATABASE=EDMS-Lok` parameter from the connection string, however I don't then seem to be able to "find" the EDMS-Lok database. E.g. if I try using

```
SELECT * FROM EDMS-Lok.dbo.eng_dwg
```

I get an error message

> Run-Time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)': [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'

(`eng_dwg` is a valid table)

When I connect without specifying a database, the `.DefaultDatabase` property of the ADO connection object returns "020" which I don't even see as an available database on that server??

When connected, if I use `SELECT name FROM sys.databases` I'm able to get a list of the databases available.  They are:

- 010
- 100
- 500
- EDMS-Lok
- Master
- msdb
- MSLLockDB
- pubs
- tempdb

I got it working using DSN, but I don't want to use DSN.

Not sure what is wrong here??

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the database name in [ ] ... like this DATABASE=[EDMS-Lok]

Comment: I just did, and got partial success.  I first tried wrapping the database name in the connection string i.e. `DATABASE=[EDMS-Lok]` and this did not work (same error).  However, if I connect without specifying the database, I'm able to access the table using `SELECT * FROM [EDMS-Lok].dbo.eng_dwg`  
So, partial success - any idea why it works in the select statement but not in the connection string?  
  
Also, I realized I had the `TrustedConnection` parameter set to `YES` and I was trying to specify credentials, so I changed that to `NO`.

Comment: It didn't work in the connection string because the string is not T-SQL code.  To get it to work, you may need to figure out how to escape the dash character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, credit for this answer should go to Dee and Sam who commented on the original question, however I can't mark a comment as the answer, so here it is:

Needed to wrap the database name in square brackets [ ] ... like this DATABASE=[EDMS-Lok] - (credit to DEE)

I first tried wrapping the database name in the connection string i.e. DATABASE=[EDMS-Lok] and this did not work (same error). However, if I connect without specifying the database, I'm able to access the table using SELECT * FROM [EDMS-Lok].dbo.eng_dwg

It didn't work in the connection string because the string is not T-SQL code. To get it to work, you may need to figure out how to escape the dash character. – (credit to SAM)

I've tried single and double quotes, backslash, square brackets, parentheses and curly brackets and nothing seems to work to escape the hyphen in the database name within the connection string. But, since I can now access the database and the tables I need, which was the original question, I wanted to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the problem is that you mix up the authentication models. You provide user + password but also you have configured trusted connection = yes. I'm not sure how ADO works in that case but I would assume that it doesn't use the configured user and connects with the windows account. Delete the trusted connection parameter in the connection string and try again.

Comment: Hi cboden, I commented on Dee's comment above regarding this - I noticed it shortly after posting and corrected the TrustedConnection parameter.